# Need to put items on 2 extreme ends in bootstrap reactjs

Tags: css

I have to print below on top of the record.

[image]

```
<h3 >CERTIFICATE DETAILS  {new Date().getDate()+'/'+ new Date().getMonth()+'/'+new Date().getFullYear()+ ''}</h3>
```

I have to put Certificate Details on the `Left` and date on the `right` on same `row`. As of now they both are coming on the `center`. how to do it.

Comment: Use flex, space-between

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code snippet.

```css
.div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="div">
      <h3>CERTIFICATE DETAILS<h3>
      <h3>24/10/2021</h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```